# Digitizing polygons by cut or split feature tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, digitizing

For saving digitizing time i created one polygon feature cover all satellite imagery (study area) and styled it outline, tried many tools inside qgis 2.18 to split / cut polygon features (i don't mean split polygon start from edge polygon feature) but digitize building inside polygon by split it.

I did this task by ArcGIS for Desktop!.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Fill Ring located under Advanced Digitizing tool

[image]

It will create a ring inside the polygon

Before using Fill Ring:

[image]

After using Fill Ring:

[image]

The above yellow polygon is just a selection to show that is not overlapping polygons. Fill polygon splits the polygons not adding another polygon:

[image]

Update:

In ArcGIS if you want to cut polygon you need to do the following:

- Select the polygon you want to cut
- Using Cut polygon tool

[image]

- Enable Snap to Sketch

[image]

- Cut the selected polygon

[image]

Comment: thank you @ahmadhanb, but fill ring tool not cut another polygon, it's just overlapping, that is mean if want to calculate shapearea will not be real

Comment: @GISMan No it does not add another polygon, it splits the polygons

Comment: <img src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/77003455fd6e8be14e1b7b42d041b56d3fb8985e77ec890463baa85c555a4873a377a786.jpg">

Comment: @GISMan Are you using ArcGIS or QGIS?

Comment: i just showing you the difference between each other, i' am a new qgis user, migrating from commercial gis software to gis open source

Comment: You are doing it in wrong way in ArcGIS. please see the update

Comment: ok thank you very much, you are right and sorry for misunderstanding